# jQuery change() with live() in 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, live

I have a `<select>` element which I need to track using change().

```
jQuery('.dropdown').change(function(){  

yada, yada

});
```

Works perfectly on already created elements. However, if I dynamically create the `<select>`, it (obviously) doesn't work. Now, I'm stuck with jQuery 1.3.2 (long story), so if I use something like:

```
jQuery('.dropdown').live('change', function(){  

 yada, yada

});
```

doesn't work.

So, any ideas? How can I make this work with dynamically created elements?

Comment: I think that you have a bug in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

    $('select').live('change', function(){

     alert(this.value);

    });

   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <p>
    <select name="numeros">
     <option value="0">cero</option>
     <option value="1">uno</option>
     <option value="2">dos</option>
    </select>
   </p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery 1.4.2
`$('select').live('change', function(){`
works with FF, Safari, Opera, but not for IE

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, onchange event is not supported by `live()` try to use [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

Comment: That's not true, I just tested jquery-1.3.2.min.js and it works